# Кликать кнопки одного сайта с другого сайта

Tags: python, selenium, тестирование

Каким образом можно кликать по кнопке на сайте скриптом, работающем на другом сайте (причём этот сайт размещён на виртуальном хостинге)? Локально всё работает с помощью Selenium.

Загвоздка возникла в том, что Selenium необходим веб-драйвер, а это исполнительный файл. На виртуальном хостинге невозможно запускать исполнительные файлы. Какие могут быть альтернативы кроме аренды VPS?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению в общем случае это невозможно, поэтому просто смените хостинг

---

Дело в том что `клик по кнопке` в большинстве случаев, это исполнение js скрипта. Поэтому без среды исполнения этот клик невозможен. Но вы можете посмотреть мб `клик по кнопке` это просто отправка некого запроса. Тогда тебе нужно просто отправить этот запрос самому

Comment: Там хитрая система. Запрос пытался определить, но тщетно. Спасибо за ответ.